# How does sw-toolbox router rule order/priority work?

Tags: router, service-worker, sw-toolbox

In my service worker (which uses sw-toolbox library) I have setup two routes as follows:

```
toolbox.router.any("/user/*", toolbox.networkOnly);
toolbox.router.any("/user/logout", toolbox.logoutHandler);
```

I assumed that the second rule which is specific to the "/user/logout" path, would act as an exception to the first rule (which is a blanket rule for the path "/user/*") however, I can confirm that it does not.

Am I using this sw-toolbox route config correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the rules are independent, first matching rule wins. So this should works:

```
toolbox.router.any("/user/logout", toolbox.logoutHandler);
toolbox.router.any("/user/*", toolbox.networkOnly);
```

See Jeff's comment on [this issues](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-toolbox/issues/95): "The routing to handlers should match in the order they're registered"

Comment: Thanks Stef. Tested and confirmed. Turns out my service worker wasnt updating during my previous tests of shuffling the order of these around.